# What differentiates the usage of MI and MI3 in collocation analysis?

Tags: corpora, collocations, entropy, corpus-linguistics

In Brezina (2018), it is stated that to measure collocation strength, one may use the Mutual Information (MI) to test the collocational strength of a given collocation. MI is naturally more sensitive to infrequent and exclusive collocations.

The formula for MI is:

log2(O11/E11),

where

O11 = frequency of collocation

E11 = expected frequency of collocation.

In addition to the MI measurement, Brezina added MI3 measurement, which is the same measure as MI but is more sensitive to exclusive, frequent collocations. Generally the formula stays the same, the only difference is that a power of 3 is given to O11, therefore the corresponding formula is as follows:

log2(O11^3/E11)

Can anybody tell me what is this power of three in the MI3 is called? I tried to find that exact formula online but to no extent. Is it a general practice in statistics? And why exactly giving a power of three to result in such change, that is, making the MI more sensitive to frequent and exclusive collocations?

I hope my question is clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to state what program you are using. Yes, MI3  is the cubed variant of the mutual information statistic. You need this paper: https://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/jbp/ijcl/2015/00000020/00000002/art00001?crawler=true